# Is it possible to indent the line numbers in algorithmicx the same as in Listings?

Tags: listings, algorithmicx, algorithmic

By default, the line numbers in `algorithmicx` are inside the float rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Input1}{$s_0 \ldots s_7, c$}
    \For{$i \gets 0$ to 7}
    \State $arr[i][0] \gets s_i$
    \EndFor
    \State $color \gets c$
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possible to change their indentation to make them display outside the float rules, like in the `listings` package? (Details omitted in picture) If the solution would change the indentation of the pseudocode as well so that they would be indented where the line numbers originally were, that would be great.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following lines below `\usepackage{algorithmicx}` (or `\usepackage{algpseudocode}` in your case).

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\algorithmic{\leftmargin\labelwidth}{\leftmargin-\labelsep}{}{}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\algorithmic{\leftmargin\labelwidth}{\leftmargin-\labelsep}{}{}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Input1}{$s_0 \ldots s_7, c$}
    \For{$i \gets 0$ to 7}
    \State $arr[i][0] \gets s_i$
    \EndFor
    \State $color \gets c$
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm very interested in understanding how this works. I know how `\xpatchcmd` works, but I don't fully understand the replaced/replacement code. I also don't know how to figure out that a solution is to patch the `algorithmic` command. May I request some links or insight on how the label manipulation works and how to arrive at this fix?

Comment: @John I checked the implementation of the `algorithmic` environment in `algorithmicx.sty`. There, I found that the indentation is hard-coded as `\leftmargin\labelwidth \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}`. This means that one either has to redefine the whole environment with a slightly modified code, or patch it in a way that `\leftmargin` is `0pt` in the end. There are several ways to do this. One could also replace `\leftmargin\labelwidth \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}` by `\leftmargin0pt`.

Comment: @John Moreover, the code for `\begin{env}` is implemented by `\env` and the one for `\end{env}` by `\endenv`.